# access relation inside hasMany relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model request.php has this relation :

```
public function requestItems(): HasMany
        {
            return $this->hasMany(RequestItemd::class, 'request_id', 'id');
        }
```

inside this relation there is another relation

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'item_id', 'id');
}
```

how to reach to belongsTo relation and retrieve data through the original hasMany relation?

Comment: You can retrieve data from the belongsTo relation by calling it on each instance of the hasMany relation.

Comment: could you please describe more

Answer (score -1):

You will need to loop over your items or get the individual item, something like this:

```
$requestItemsQuery->each(function($reqestItmId) {
  $item = $reqestItmId->item;
});
```

there are a few other ways of doing this though, so if you share how you are planning to use the reference i might be able to give a better answer

Comment: thats how I retreive data  $requestItems = Request::with('requestItems')->where('id', $id)                    ->first();

Comment: when I use with('requestItems.item') I got error

Comment: You might need to share some more code so we can see the structure of your 2 models, something doesn't seem right with how you are using it.

Comment: I want to get 'item' data with requestItems relation

Comment: I just find the issue , its with item model which has a binary column , when I hide this column it works fine but I still need the binary column. could you please help me ?